# What exactly does TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso() return?

Tags: android, geolocation, telephonymanager

I want to find out which country the user is currently in, in the event that a data connection is not available (so `Geocoder` doesn't work). I think I can do this on phones (not tablets) by using `TelephonyManager.getNetworkCountryIso`, but I find the documentation is not quite clear enough for me. The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getNetworkCountryIso()) says:

> Returns the ISO country code equivalent of the **current registered
>   operator**'s MCC (Mobile Country Code).
>
> Availability: Only when user is registered to a network. Result may be
>   unreliable on CDMA networks (use getPhoneType() to determine if on a
>   CDMA network).

What is the precise meaning of **current registered operator** here? Does this simply mean the network which the user is currently connected to, wherever in the world they may be, independent of where their SIM is registered (the "home" network)?

And in what sense is the result **unreliable on CDMA networks**? Does this mean it may return `null`, or give a non-`null` but misleading or inaccurate result?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the MCC is dependent on where you are in the world. 
A lot of the world doesn't use CDMA, rendering your phone incapable of connection in some situations. I believe it just returns an inaccurate result in those cases.