# If i move from China to US, Does the TelephoneManager.getNetworkCountryIso() return the same value?

Tags: android, location

Does the TelephoneManager.getNetworkCountryIso() return the same value if i moved to another country?

Comment: this might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26789128/what-exactly-does-telephonymanager-getnetworkcountryiso-return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you brought your China SIM Card and use it in USA (roaming), then *TelephoneManager.getNetworkCountryIso()* might show incorrect or even unexpected result.

also *TelephoneManager.getNetworkCountryIso()* only reliable on device connected to GSM Network